# Pandas check value in column

Tags: python, pandas

I'm not used to pandas 's syntax, i'm trying to just check if a value is in a column.
i've tested this :
data = my dataframe
ini = column name

```
data = pdsql.read_sql_query("select id_bdcarth, id_nd_ini::int ini, id_nd_fin::int fin, v from tempturbi.tmp_somme_v19",connection)

exists = 973237173 in data.ini 
print(exists)
```

and i get False as result (but the value is in the column). Is my method wrong ?

Comment: `(data["ini"]==973237173).any()`?

Comment: thanks it works !